# Labels on figures fail to display in a deployed Matlab application

Tags: matlab, figure

I have a Matlab application deployed using Builder JA.  I incorporated it into a larger Java-based web application.  It was built on a Windows machine, which has actual matlab on it, and worked fine when I tested it there.  I've deployed the application onto a Linux server, which has only the MCR on it.  what happens now is that I can run the application via the web page, but the resulting graphs display only the graphics and not the text (title, axis labels, etc).  This happens both when I use WebFigure(gcf) and when I use figtoImStream(gcf, jpg), so I don't think it's an issue with any one format.  The issue seems to be in the hardcopy.p function, since the server logs show an error

```
{Warning: Failed to draw text string} 
{> In /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v717/toolbox/matlab/graphics/hardcopy.p>hardcopy at 28
  In compiler/private/hardcopyOutput at 58
  In figToImStream at 73
  In Gaussian_WBfigures_jpg at 635}
```

I've seen some things that suggest that this is an issue of Matlab looking for a font that isn't there, and some that suggest that this is an issue with the renderer.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try to change the `Renderer` property of the figure?

Comment: have not tried that.   I assumed that MCR wouldn't be able to deal with another renderer, but let me try that.

Comment: Just tried all three possible renderers.  Same issue with all three (actually, openGL isn't available on the server, so it defaulted to ZBuffer)

Comment: Hmm.. sorry to hear that. I think that your best bet is Mathworks in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try plotting your labels with a different fonts or interpreters. there have been reports of bugs in matlab when printing with different interpreters. e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/398506, http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/309380

```
figure
text(0.5,0.5,'testa','Fontname','Arial')
text(0.5,0.6,'testa','Fontname','Times')
text(0.5,0.7,'testa','Fontname','Times','Interpreter','Tex')
text(0.5,0.8,'testa','Fontname','Times','Interpreter','Latex')
```